# Is it possible to make a bootstrap vue prop dynamic?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to create multiple accordions, based on the number of elements received, using bootstrap vue components.

I've created an accordion, similar to how the docs suggest: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse#accordion-support

Now, I only want clicking on one element to open that accordion. I have given a dynamic id (the index from the parent v-for element) using v-bind, and now want to set the prop `v-b-toggle.accordion-{{index}}`, where index is the index from the v-for.

I've added *** before and after the prop in the code below to help find it.

Here's my code below to hopefully explain more:

```
 <b-card
                v-for="(book, index) in data"
                :key="index"
                no-body
                class="mb-1"
              >
                <b-card-header header-tag="header" class="p-1" role="tab">
                  <b-button block ***v-b-toggle.accordion-{{index}}*** variant="light"
                    >{{ book.title }} <span class="mx-4"> - </span>
                    {{ book.rating }}</b-button
                  >
                </b-card-header>
                <b-collapse
                  :id="String('accordion-' + (index))"
                  accordion="my-accordion"
                  role="tabpanel"
                >
                  <b-card-body style="min-height: 300px">
                    <b-card-text>
                     {{book.review}}
                    </b-card-text>
                  </b-card-body>
                </b-collapse>
              </b-card>
```

Hard coding it as `b-toggle.accordion-1` works, so I think the dynamic value for :id works. I just can't get the accordion number dynamic.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `v-bind="{'v-b-toggle.accordion-'+index: true}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

In the b-button, I ended up with:

```
v-b-toggle="'accordion-' + index"
```

and in the b-collapse:

```
:id="'accordion-' + index"
```